# How to iterate a list without the last element

Tags: c++, iterator

What I want to do is just iterate a `std::list` except for the last element. What I am trying:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>

int main() {
  std::list<int> *list = new std::list<int>(100);
  std::list<int>::iterator it;

  for (it = list->begin(); it != list->end()-1; it++) {
    // some action here...
  }
}
```

However, this will not work. What is wrong?

Comment: please be more explicit when you say "this will not work", does that mean "it doesn't compile" or "it crashes" or "doesn't do what I expect"?

Comment: Try using `list->rbegin() - 1` instead of `list->end() - 1`.

Comment: That pointer looks pretty meaningless. `std::list<int> list(100);` should do. If you absolutely need a pointer, use a smart pointer so you don't have to manually free the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::list` uses a bidirectional iterator, which doesn't support `operator-`. Use `std::prev` instead:

```
for (it = list->begin(); it != std::prev(list->end()); it++) {
  // some action here...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As to why this fails:

A `list::iterator` is a `BidirectionalIterator`. It cannot be decrement using `operator-` or increment using `operator+`. Those operations are reserved for models of `RandomAccessIterator`. However, you can decrement it using `operator--`.

```
std::list<int> x;
// --end(x) would work as well here, but I don't recommend it
auto end = end(x); 
--end;

// or even better
end = std::prev(end(x));

for(auto it = begin(x); it != end; ++it) {

}
```

Also, please drop the pointers. Your simple example is already leaking memory.